# Does FSEventStreamCreate really require directories?

Tags: macos

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1443980-fseventstreamcreate?language=objc), the fourth parameter of `FSEventStreamCreate` (a function used to receive events about file changes) is "A CFArray of CFStringRefs, each specifying a *path to a directory*, ..." but I'm interested in changes to a specific *file* only. I know that I can pass the directory the file is in and then filter the events, which is what I've been doing up until now, but I have found out, that if I simply pass the file's entire path, it works perfectly fine (and allows me to simplify my code significantly).

So my question is, since I want to put this into production software, is this something I can rely on to work (e.g. in other versions of the OS), or is it a fluke? Is it documented somewhere to work this way? Does anyone else use it this way? My best guess is that the documentation is phrased like this because by default, only filesystem changes are reported, and the flag `kFSEventStreamCreateFlagFileEvents` has to be added to make it also report file content changes, but maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing Apple says about this is [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1455376-fseventstreamcreateflags/kfseventstreamcreateflagfileevents?language=objc)

> Request file-level notifications. Your stream will receive events about individual files in the hierarchy you're watching instead of only receiving directory level notifications.

Regarding other developers using this feature: yes, there [are](https://github.com/rjeczalik/notify) [some](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch).

You can probably leave a feedback on Apple, asking to improve the documentation, and maybe one day they will.